# Creating ajax forms with ajax

Tags: 7, forms, ajax, javascript

I have been trying to implement popup forms that load dynamically, which initially seemed pretty easy. My current method is to echo the form from a menu callback, and insert it where needed with js. The problem I have been having though, is that any ajax controls (or submit) within the form require the ajax behaviour to be rerun on the added form.

On the surface this can be solved by simply running `Drupal.attachBehaviors()` after inserting the form, however the ajax system utilises the `Drupal.settings` built by the drupal renderer. As the settings information isn't passed with my form, my only solution is to send both the form and settings as json, and fiddle with the settings to make them match the required format.

Is this the only way to go about it, or is there a much simpler way I am missing?

Comment: Are you using Ctools ?

Comment: Yeah, I can incorporate it.